# application crashes

Tags: iphone, ipad

my application gets crashes by getting this error!!! :(

**objc[12723]: FREED(id): message clientID sent to freed object=0x48a23e0**

may i know the reason for this!!

Thanks

Comment: ... and by the way, you should definitively accept some answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a message to an object that has been deallocated!

I recommend that you read through the [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/memorymgmt.html) from Apple.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is written...

You are calling the `clientID` method on an object that has been freed.
Maybe you forgot to retain it at some place...

Answer (score 1):

You're sending a message to a released object. Check your memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Tthere's not much information in your question for us to help you but this is what is happening :

1) You have made an object and then released it.

```
myObject =[MyObject alloc] init];
...
[myObject release];
```

2) Later on you've tried to do something like

```
[myObject clientID];
```

but it's already been released so it doesn't exist anymore.

If you edit your question and add some more code from where the crash happens we might be able to help more.